# How are Stack Exchange sites officially branded?

Tags: support, faq, trademark

How are sites in the Stack Exchange network, including Stack Overflow, officially branded? How are their names abbreviated? What conventions should be used in the FAQ?

[Return to FAQ Index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Comment: Does this really need a [FAQ]?

Comment: @AsheeshR given this question was asked today? Yes.

Comment: The answer is *just* a link to the Trademarks page.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Casing, spacing and other branding/trademark guidance can be mined and further explored at  [Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange Trademarks](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

The page is accessible through the "legal" link in the footer of every Stack Exchange network page.

Comment: It's important to note that the SO logo is NOT licensed under cc-wiki. "site design / **logo** © 2011 stack overflow internet services, inc; user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required"

Comment: Yup, that's why I said if you use the Stack Overflow logo, it should probably fall under Fair Use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use

Answer (score 11):

You really should go read the legalese (specifically, the last paragraph). But in case you won't or can't, here's a quick summary:

- The company is legally named **Stack Exchange, Inc.** It uses the brand name **Stack Overflow**.
- The websites are named **Stack Overflow**, **Super User**, **Cross Validated**, **User Experience**, etc. That's a U+0020 SPACE separating multiple words.

  - **Exception:** [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net) is two words smashed together. That trademark gets special treatment because [it is actually owned by the MathOverflow corporation](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/970); Stack Exchange Inc. just licenses it.
- All of those and more are **Stack Exchange sites** (separated by U+0020 SPACE; also note capitalisation).
- Those sites live on the **Stack Exchange Network** (all words initial-caps, separated by U+0020 SPACE).
- You can't name an app **Stack Exchange XYZ** or **Stack Overflow XYZ**. You may, however, call it **Stack XYZ**, **XYZ Overflow**, or something like that. *Usually.* Use common sense.

  1. If it could easily be confused with something official, you probably shouldn't use it.
  2. When in doubt, check with Stack Exchange Inc.

     - https://stackoverflow.com/contact
     - `mailto:team@stackexchange.com`

Comment: It should perhaps be noted explicitly that not for all Stack Exchange sites it is Stack Exchange Inc. that is the authority to ask for usage of the name. An example, I do not know if it the only one, is [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net), which is also spelled *without* space. See http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/969/who-owns-mathoverflow for information on who owns MathOverflow

Comment: @quid Oh, I was going to put that in, but forgot about it during drafting... **(edit)** There, done.

Comment: This is slightly outdated: the company is no longer **Stack Exchange inc.** rather [it's gone back](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/) to **StackOverflow**

Comment: @Mooz The [legal page](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) hasn't changed...

Comment: Regarding that last point...Are Stack Apps (such as browser plugins meant to be used on Stack Exchange) allowed to have "Stack Exchange" in their names? I made an add-on called "Stack Exchange Downvoter." Is that an illegal use of the trademark?