# What is the proper spacing of the "Stack Overflow" name?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-overflow-name

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is Stack Overflow Officially Branded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9024/how-is-stack-overflow-officially-branded)

My questions/answers have been edited multiple times now due to a simple thing: whether to write Stack Overflow (or Super User) as Stack Overflow or as StackOverflow. One edit of one of the posts edited it to the first way, the other edit of the other post edited it to the other way. So, what is the correct way of writing it? Oh, and also, feel free to edit the title of this question. :)

Comment: Why would anyone write out Super User as Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Shog9 LOL! :D thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @random well you know what I meant... right? I don't know why I chose Super User... I <3 all trilogy sites!

Comment: Oh, ya, it is a duplicate, I just didn't find it. Sorry about that, and thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9024/how-is-stack-overflow-officially-branded).