# Why don't the activity badges track across sites?

Tags: discussion

Is there a specific reason why the "visit for x days" badges do not track across different communities? I kind of can understand the reasoning behind why privileges are tied to a single community, but why not this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The entire system just isn't set up in a way for that to make sense. First, none of the other badges are that way, so these badges conform to the standard. Second, if you earned these badges by visiting different sites, which site(s) would the badge be earned on? Balance-wise, it shouldn't be all of them, but anything else is kinda arbitrary.

Comment: Yeah, especially the second point. How would it be supposed to work at all?

Comment: Alright, so what's wrong with the balance if badges are distributed for active users across all sites? Biographer, for one, works on any Stackexchange site. Having to visit every single community every day when much of the relevant information can be found elsewhere (inbox, hot questions, etc) seems very redundant.

Comment: @mmKALLL you get Biographer badge instantly because the "About us" is copied when you join a new site, and that fulfills the requirement. But for "visit x days", the reason there's a badge for that is actually to encourage you to *participate actively* on that site, not just visiting the site just to get the badge. For example: can you be a "Fanatic" if you only visit the site for 100 days without doing anything?

Comment: @AndrewT. Do you think that one is not a "Fanatic", even if they visit SE every day _for multiple months_ and help a wide range of communities rather than just one or two?

Comment: @mmKALLL Well, Fanatic to SE perhaps, but not to any particular community. All badges are applied to a site, not network-wide, unless you want to request to have SE network-wide badge (which is a [tag:feature-request]).

Comment: @AndrewT. Well, what I really want to understand are the design decisions that went into making communities so segregated. I would guess that most users outside SO are regulars at two communities or more, which is why the concept is very unintuitive for a newcomer such as myself. Perhaps this is something I should post a new question about?

Comment: @mmKALLL "*I would guess that most users outside SO are regulars at two communities or more*" without data, this is only an assumption. There's nothing stopping you to ask a new question, but I encourage you to research more on here to understand how SE was established, and how the network works. Previously, [there are only 3 sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50912/what-is-the-correct-name-to-use-when-referencing-the-trilogy-sites), so they probably didn't think of the problem when it became [so many](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70771/too-many-se-sites-causes-confusio)