# What is the accepted, cool kid, abbreviation for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, terminology

I reference it at work, and I'm too lazy to type Stack Overflow into Office Communicator, plus it eats away at my character limit.  Also, it would help if I could differentiate between the website and the occasion when I accidentally the whole CLR.

Comment: Related: [How is Stack Overflow Officially Branded?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9024/how-is-stack-overflow-officially-branded) and [What should the users of Stack Overflow be called?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/what-should-the-users-of-stack-overflow-be-called)

Comment: @TylerH no, it doesn't. One has to search long time to see the answer they seek, that's not the goal of duplicates.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard This question is asking what the abbreviation for Stack Overflow is, but in an opinion-based way. The alternative is it gets closed as POB with no useful linkage, or it gets closed as a duplicate the canonical abbreviation glossary. You also don't have to search very long; it took me a total of 9 seconds to scroll down to Stack Overflow's "SO" entry once the page loaded. This is exactly the kind of question that the duplicate system is designed to handle.

Answer (score 9):

SO is the most common abbreviation I regularly encounter.

Answer (score 6):

I usually call it SO,TBSITWTGATYPQ.

Comment: The "TB" is probably "To Be", "WT" is "With The", and "PQ" must be the "Parti Québécois"... I can't decipher the rest.

Comment: Stack Overflow, the biggest site in the world that gallops a turnip yogurt pony queen?

Comment: StackOverflow, this being strictly in the words that Geralds awkward toddler Yolanda posited querulously

Comment: Are you sure this is the right abbreviation? It doesn't contain "EE". Sorry, I mean "E-E".

Comment: The best site in the world to get answers to your posted questions? Why am I doing this?

Comment: Stack Overflow, the best site in the world to get answers to your programming questions.